# SharePoint 2013 - Modifying the navigation menu

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation, sub-site, team-sites

I was wondering why the navigation menu in team sites looks different on different pages/sub-sites.

To give you an example:

How it should look site-wide: (It seems that this menu is only appearing on `https://*.*******.*/_layouts/15/settings.aspx`)

[image]

How the main page appears:
[image]

Is there any way I could fix this so that the menu in the first image is displayed site-wide? The menu in the first image is only view-able in some sub-sites but not the main page for example.

Also is it possible to remove the 'National Statistics Office' (site name) from the navigation bar?

EDIT: Global Navigation Menu

[image]

This is the master page settings page (everything by default except the alternate css).

[image]

All sub-sites except the main site have the navigation menu correct. It seems that only the main portal is not displaying the navigation menu correctly and all the sub-sites are inheriting navigation from the parent site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Q#1, check to see if it's using different master page on the root site. Check for any errors in the console. From your screenshot, it looks like the all the menu items are present but flattened out (i.e no dynamic drop down navigation) Switch to original master page for one of the two master pages(custom or system) see if it works.

For your Q#2,

If you look into the html output (use Firebug or IE tools), you'd see how SharePoint constructs the structured navigation. The root site becomes the first anchor child and all other are in turn the children of li with class 'static'. 
Add the following CSS to your stylesheet 'style.css':

```
div.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox > ul.ms-core-listMenu-root > li.static > a {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have all sub-sites inheriting navigation from the parent site and it's working. The only problem is that the parent site itself is not adhering to the navigation structure!

Comment: Did you check console for any error logs?

Comment: Is this security trimmed and spanning across site collections? I am direly in need of a solution for implementing a security trimmed, cross-site collection navigation menu that works for SharePoint 2016.

Comment: take a look at: https://eschrader.com/2017/05/24/sharepoint-online-global-navigation-across-site-collections/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove Page Title 'National Statistics Office' (site name) using below custom CSS code

```
/* custom css to remove the page title */
h1.ms-core-pageTitle { display:none; }
```

for the menu, can you please explain more as both images look like same so its hard to identify the problem.

As i understand here that you want same navigation in all subsites from main site.For that you can follow these steps mentioned in below location.

[Configure Global Navigation in SharePoint 2010](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/configure-global-navigation-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

**It is for SharePoint 2010 but it will work same in SharePoint 2013 as well.**

Comment: My bad.. uploaded wrong image. Updated question with proper image!

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If you need something else than please let me know.

Comment: It seems that they already are in the right order, however, the menu is not the same site-wide.

Comment: With regards to removing the site title from the nav bar.. which CSS file do I need to modify?

Comment: The code above is the css part which you should add in a Script editor but you should put Style Tag in both side: <style>h1.ms-core-pageTitle { display:none; } </style>

Comment: @Shadi Yes but I should put it in the masterpage/create new css? I don't udnerstand. I cannot modify the masterpage as it prompts me to save it with another name.

Comment: @Shadi What I did is create Style.css and from the Master Page page I set the alternate CSS to Style.css but the site name is still visible in the navigation menu.

Comment: of you set an alternate css you should find this element in your CSS document   h1.ms-core-pageTitle    then add display:none in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For Setting the navigation same as parent site you can go to **Navigation** link in **Site Setting** in each sub site and chose inherit from parent site navigation and it will work perfectly. 
[image]

Comment: That option is not clickable. Is there a logic behind this?

Comment: That option would only apply to sub-sites.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in question, the navigation appearing correctly on Setting page but not on main page, then make sure that **Site Master Page** and **System Master Page** are same.

[image]

There might be possibility that, **System Master Page** is using actual Navigation and **Site master page** is using some custom navigation

Comment: @P S kindly see my updated question with images.